# Uniswap V3 uncollected fees calculation

Tags: uniswap

According to the whitepaper, when a position is in range

> uncollected fees = liquidity( feeGrowthGlobal - feeGrowthOutsidelowerTick - feeGrowthOutsideUpperTick - feeGrowthInside)

But for stable coins `feeGrowthGlobal - feeGrowthOutsideLowerTick - feeGrowthOutsideUpperTick` seems negative, resulting in negative uncollected fees.

Example

```
 {
        "id": "149982",
        "liquidity": "70751535817529022692995",
        "pool": {
          "feeGrowthGlobal0X128": "1218682304163016184766177108699434636279"
        },
        "tickLower": {
          "feeGrowthOutside0X128": "1145577432605598277662216874263285465942"
        },
        "tickUpper": {
          "feeGrowthOutside0X128": "1125981180184479101654443162252506477054"
        },
        "token0": {
          "symbol": "DAI"
        },
        "token1": {
          "symbol": "WETH"
        }
      },
```

`1218682304163016184766177108699434636279 - 1145577432605598277662216874263285465942 - 1125981180184479101654443162252506477054 = -1052876308627061194550482927816357306717`

Answer (score 0):

My two cents:

I wrote a function that perform a static call passing the maximum collectable value in other to see how much is pending to be collected.

```
export const calculatePendingFees = async (
  tokenId: number,
  recipient: string,
  amount0Max: BigNumber,
  amount1Max: BigNumber,
  chainId: number
) => {
  try {
    const params = {
      tokenId: tokenId,
      recipient: recipient,
      amount0Max: amount0Max,
      amount1Max: amount1Max,
    }

    const nonfungible = new ethers.Contract(
      NONFUNGIBLE_POSITION_MANAGER_ADDRESS[chainId],
      Nonfungiblepositionmanager.abi,
      PROVIDER[chainId]
    )

    const feesGenerated = await nonfungible.callStatic.collect(params)
    return feesGenerated
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message, "calculate fees error")
  }
}
```

For `amount0Max`and `amount1Max`you can use this:

```
const MAX_UINT128 = BigNumber.from(2).pow(128).sub(1)
```

This function will return to you the uncollected fees :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to account for potential under- or over-flow when doing math on the unsigned integer values. More specifically, the Uniswap V3 contract *expects* the `feeGrowthGlobal - feeGrowthOutsideLowerTick - feeGrowthOutsideUpperTick` formula to wrap-around 256 bits (i.e. modulo), which can be surprising if your language implements BigInts natively (e.g. Python). My Python library [Pyuv3](https://github.com/someben/pyuv3/blob/main/pyuv3/pos.py#L15) handles this correctly, for example.